# If EXE opens, then RUN

Tags: if-statement, vbscript

I need a script that. If exe opens, then URL will open. And I did make a shortcut for the URL.

I found this script, on stack overflow, and was going to use it changing the arguments of course, but I figured there would be a simpler way

EDIT: If League of Legends.exe opens [This is the client itself], then run C:..\KSD.url

```
Option Explicit

Private Const Folder As String = "c:\windows\system32\foldername"
Private Const FileToRun As String = "\\servername\folder\software.exe"

Sub Run(ByVal sFile)
    Dim shell
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    shell.Run Chr(34) & sFile & Chr(34), 1, False
    Set shell = Nothing
End Sub

Dim fs
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not fs.FolderExists(Folder) Then
   Run FileToRun
End If
```

Comment: This can't be Java.... Is it? :-O

Comment: @syb0rg Can't be C++ either, VB?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That tag was there originally, I just know it wasn't Java or C++, marking as [VB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic).

Comment: I removed C++, it's not C++...

Comment: I have no idea what the actual question is here. You've posted a very vague, unclear description of what you want that doesn't make much sense, and a block of VBScript code that doesn't seem to have anything to do with that vague description. You need to [edit] your question to more clearly explain the problem you're trying to solve and how that VBScript code might relate to that problem. Adding random tags that have nothing to do with the question doesn't help, either; your question is strictly about VBScript, and has nothing to do with Java or C++. If you want help, be clear and specific.

Comment: Edited."EDIT: If League of Legends.exe opens [This is the client itself], then run C:..\KSD.url"

Comment: What do you mean by "if League of Legends.exe opens"? Do you want the script to run in the background and detect when this client is started?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Exec` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a(v=vs.84).aspx

```
objExec = shell.Exec Chr(34) & sFile & Chr(34)
if objExec.Status = 0 then ' your program is running
  ' open your url
end if
```

You may need error handling if your file does not open (see MSDN documenation above).  Please code responsibly :-)